# Wordpress shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I built a very unique and javascript intensive theme for wordpress and now shortcodes do not work. I do not have any plugins installed, so it's not that. What did I drop from my wordpress template files that is required to use shortcodes (ie: [gallery]).

I understand how to make shortcodes, but how does WP take your post and replace "[gallery]" when it is spitting it back out for display?

EDIT:
here is what I'm currently working with:

```
    $pagepull = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY menu_order", ARRAY_A);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($pagepull as $single_page){
     echo "<div class=\"section\"><ul><li class=\"sub\" id=\"" . $i  . "\"><div class=\"insection\">";
         echo $single_page['post_content'];
$i++;
// more code that is irrelevant...
// more code that is irrelevant...
// more code that is irrelevant...
    }
```

Comment: Short answer: you are using the raw content ($single_page['post_content']) instead the filtered one: apply the_content filter. echo apply_filters('the_content',$single_page['post_content']);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, try this

```
 $pagepull = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY menu_order", ARRAY_A);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($pagepull as $single_page){
     echo "<div class=\"section\"><ul><li class=\"sub\" id=\"" . $i  . "\"><div class=\"insection\">";
         echo apply_filters('the_content',$single_page['post_content']);
$i++;
```

Wordpress take your content and apply filters to it. You must register a filter and let  parse your content.

If your theme is not displaying your shortcodes, probabily you output the content of the post without let Wordpress filter it.

Calling the function get_the_content() for a post, does not run the filter for shortcodes (if any).

To have apply

```
<?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Note: many plugins register filters with the content to implement shortcodes!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Any chance you could make a comment on my new edit?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was replacing

```
<?= get_the_content() ?>
```

with

```
<?= the_content() ?>
```

which, as keatch already mentioned, applies filters before returning content.

[Read this carefully about the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Alternative_Usage)

Answer (score 1):

use this if you want the content inside a variable:

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

now you could just do echo $content; or use regex or whatever you want to make the content look like how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Shortcodes depends on WP Loop, but that's a different issue. To make a long story short, I've added `the_post();` at the page that should be showing the shortcode (for example `articles.php`).

Also, make sure that you are using `the_content()` in order to display the text (using `$post->post_data` for example won't show you shortcodes).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the

```
ob_start();
```

in the starting of function and use

```
return ob_get_clean();
```

before closing the function.

Hope this will help full for you.

Cheers